# magneto 2 migration tool installation error

Tags: magento2

time of installing migration tool in magento2.2.7 getting error "vertex/sdk 1.0.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system". But soap is already installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm this things.

1. The `soap` install properly and working properly or not.
2. Better try to reinstall it again.